# Android AlertDialog does not close with radiobutton

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog with radio buttons on it. When I click on an option it inserts the value into a textview but I can not get the window to close after.

```
private void showRadioButtonDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vewInflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_installments_radiogroup,  null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    builder.setView(vewInflater);
    builder.setTitle("Dialog title");
    RadioGroup currencySettingRadioGroup = vewInflater.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    ArrayList<String> listArr = getInstallmentsList(amountToPay, 12);
    for ( String items: listArr ) {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
        rb.setText(items);
        currencySettingRadioGroup.addView(rb);
        rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rb.setChecked(true);
                TextView tvInstallments = findViewById(R.id.tvInstallments);
                tvInstallments.setText(items);
                dialog.dismiss(); // <== does not work
            }
        });

    }
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `show()` method calls `create()` internally.

You get a reference to a built Dialog by calling `builder.create()`, but Android does that too, when you call `builder.show()`. That means Android has its own Dialog instance, which your `dialog` variable isn't referencing.

Use `dialog.show()` instead of `builder.show()`.

You also need `builder.create()` to be called after you finish setting all the properties of the Builder (move it to be below `builder.setTitle()`).

Comment: So the window does not appear!

Comment: Ok. It Works. Thanks!